# add orderBy ('created_at', 'desc') to my account

Tags: php, laravel, sql-order-by

I would like to create an `orderBy ('created_at', 'desc')` and `paginate`, for my articles posted in my account, here is my code.
MyaccountController

```
 public function viewProfile($username) {

    if($username) {

        $user = User::where('username', $username)->firstOrFail();
    } else {
        $user = User::find(Auth::user()->id);
    }

    return view('site.user.account', [

        'user' => $user,
        'events' => $user->events,
        'articles' => $user->articles,


    ]);


}
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the relationship is correct on the User model:

```
'articles' => $user->articles()->orderByDesc('created_at')->paginate()
```